# What's the @njit signature for a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jit, numba

Whenever passing an array of, say, integers to a function, the @njit decorator may look like:

```
@njit("int64(int64[:])")
def myFunction(L):     # L is a one-dimensional array of 64-bit integers.
    <body of function>
    return some_integer
```

This doesn't seem to work with a list, maybe because a list can be composed of members of different types. Is there a specific signature for a list?